# How do I stop vertices being hidden by the Subsurf modifier in Edit mode?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

So I'm trying to do a model and I noticed when in *Edit* mode the vertices and edges are being hidden by the smoothed surface view:

[image]

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

There are times that the unmodified vertices of a mesh will be inside the surface created by a Subsurf modifier.

Personally, I regularly flip between view subsurf levels while I'm modeling, anyway. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>to<kbd>5</kbd> on the keyboard) Then you can edit the model in its unmodified appearance, which is often less confusing than another option, (illustrated)

[image]

which is to 'Adjust edit cage to modifier resullt'. this will result in the appearance of sliding points around on the curved, subdivided surface.

Comment: That works for now at least i can select the vertices I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the "Limit Selection to Visible" button.

[image: Limit Selection to Visible]

Comment: Nope still same thing just being able to see through it now